# jQuery Navigation conflic of nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I am trying to make a click-able navigation bar. It works in terms of nothing happens on:hover but I am not sure how to cycle through and open the tab that the user has clicked whilst closing the previous one. Currently it works, show and hide on the same `li` however it conflicts on another tab. Any help would be great.

```
var $main_menu = $('.catLevel');

$main_menu.find('li').click(function(event) {

    var clicker = $(this).data('clicker');

    if (clicker) {
        //Odd number of clicks
        console.log('Clicker .hide');

        $(this).find('.navWrap').hide();

    } else {
        //Even number of clicks
        console.log('Clicker .show');

        $(this).find('.navWrap').show();

    }
    $(this).data("clicker", !clicker);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to do is hide them all, then just show the one that was clicked. You might want to tweak this a bit but something like this should work:

```
var $main_menu = $('.catLevel'),
    $menu_kids = $main_menu.find('li');

$menu_kids.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        clicker = $(this).data('clicker');

    $menu_kids.hide(); //This hides all of them

    $this.show(); //Only show the one that was clicked. You should select the DIV with the content instead of $this.

    $this.data("clicker", !clicker);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so something like this?

```
var items = $('.catLevel').find('li');
items.click(function() {
  var clicked = $(this).find('.navWrap');
  clicked.show();
  items.find('.navWrap').not(clicked).hide();
});
```

i don't have a working DOM to test with but it might be what you're looking for.